# Github Copilot cannot launch browser to sign in from Ubuntu Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I am setting up it on my Ubuntu vscode.

The vscode sign-in process failed to launch a browser:

```
Failed to launch preferred application for category "WebBrowser".
Could not find fallback WebBrowser application
```

See screenshot
[image: screenshot]

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

VsCode Version: 1.82.0

I had latest google chrome installed (116) in the standard place:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

What configuration am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

The error message "Failed to launch preferred application" was not from vscode, but from the Ubuntu window manager. For my case, the window manager was xfce4.

Also note: this error had nothing to do with vscode's Live Server.

Basically the window manager's WebBrowser action was not bound to an application.

Therefore, the fix was to bind WebBrowser to Chrome or your preferred browser.

For my case, in xfce4, the binding was done in Application->Setting->Default Application.